# Collapse area with a data loop

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a SPA (single page application) where there is a table that should expand details.

This is the code:

```
<div class="row mt-4" *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Details
        </button>
        <div [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
            {{ row.detail}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't make it expand just the detail of the clicked column

Comment: Did you check if ng-bootstrap is installed properly?

Comment: Yep, the area expands, but all expand, not just the one that was clicked

Comment: If you have multiple rows with the same id, then it won't work, I guess.

Comment: I believe that id of the div is not relevant in this question, if I remove or if I add the id of the row in the id tag, the same thing still happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a single variable `isCollapsed` which is controlling the expand/collapse for each div (so either all will be expanded, or all will be collapsed). You haven't posted the Typescript, but I'm assuming it looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent {

  public isCollapsed: boolean = true;

  public rows: object[] = [
    { detail: 'x' },
    { detail: 'y' }
  ]; 
}
```

You would need individual `isCollapsed` variables to keep track of individual divs.

If you have control over the objects in `rows` you could add it there:

```
public rows: object[] = [
  {
    detail: 'x',
    isCollapsed: true
  },
  {
    detail: 'y',
    isCollapsed: true
  }
];
```

Then change the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="row mt-4" *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="row.isCollapsed = !row.isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!row.isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Details
        </button>
        <div [ngbCollapse]="row.isCollapsed">
            {{ row.detail}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will allow you to have control over expanding/collapsing individual divs. Please see [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C46mnJpT0MsEP4FVQLYM?p=preview) for a demo

Answer (score 10):

I solved it this way, which I guess is a little more convenient than actually changing the data itself.

In the HTML section of the component, get the index of your ngFor loop and use this index-variable in the event-binding and the ngbCollapse directive.
To make this work, you need an array of booleans property in your component.ts file.

**component HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
    <button type="button" (click)="isCollapsed[i] = !isCollapsed[i]">
        Button Text
    </button>
    <div [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed[i]">
        .. some content ..
    </div>
</div>
```

**component TypeScript**

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'xxx',
  templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './xxx.component.css']
})
export class xxx{

  public isCollapsed: boolean[] = [];

}
```

Comment: I followed your instructions, but the collapse is already shown. how can I make it hide by default until clicked?

Comment: I found it!. just add "!" at the <div [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed[i]">
the result should be

<div [ngbCollapse]="!isCollapsed[i]"> //this would make your div hide at first render

the next problem is how can we make collapse div one at the time. with this set up. we can collapse them all but clicking the trigger button.

How can we make it collapse one at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

For those using  ngx-bootstrap accordions in a loop:

```
<div 
[attr.id]="setting.id" 
[class.collapse]="setting.isCollapsed" 
(collapsed)="collapsed($event)"
(expanded)="expanded($event)">
  <p>
     {{setting.isCollapsed}}
  </p> 
</div>
```